# Update row in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Table 1 that look something like this

```
EID      Hold        Source
3232     KLME         jame.k@gmail.com
         KLME         https://google.com
         EEME         david.e@gmail.com
         JJIN         Test@gmail.com
7232     JJIN         https://google.com
```

I'm just wondering how can I update the second row of hold "KLME" using the first row.

example like this

```
EID      Hold        Source
3232     KLME         jame.k@gmail.com
3232     KLME         https://google.com
         EEME         david.e@gmail.com
7232     JJIN         Test@gmail.com
7232     JJIN         https://google.com
```

```
UPDATE Test_Table 
SET EID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Test_Table.EID
    FROM Test_Table 
    WHERE Test_Table.Hold = Test_Table.Hold
    AND Test_Table.EID <> '' OR Test_Table.EID <> NULL
)
```

I have this simple script but I'm getting a different EID from different user instead of the correct EID for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX()`:

```
UPDATE Test_Table 
SET EID = (
    SELECT MAX(EID)
    FROM Test_Table a
    WHERE a.Hold = Test_Table.Hold
)
```

Note how you don't need to filter out blanks or nulls because MAX ignores nulls and any non-blank value is greater than blank.

Also, by not adding a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE`, you'll automatically correct any inconsistencies with `EID` being different for a given `Hold`.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use an updatable CTE and a window function.** The benefit of this is that the table is only scanned once.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      OtherEID = MIN(NULLIF(tt.EID, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY tt.HOLD)
    FROM Test_Table tt
)
UPDATE cte
SET EID = OtherEID
WHERE (EID IS NULL OR EID = '')
  AND OtherEID IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going wrong with your query.

1. You cannot use an equality (or inequality) check against null, you must use `IS NOT NULL`
2. You need brackets around your `OR`ed conditions to get the correct logic
3. You really only need to update rows with a missing `EID`.

A possible solution which updates the correct rows, and correlates the new value correctly is

```
UPDATE t1 SET
  EID = (SELECT TOP 1 Test_Table.EID FROM Test_Table t2 WHERE t2.[Hold] = t1.[Hold] AND COALESCE(t2.EID,'') <> '')
FROM Test_Table t1
WHERE Test_Table.EID = '' OR Test_Table.EID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `group by` and `max()` as follows :

First get the max(Eid) per Hold :

```
select Hold, max(EID) as Eid
from Test_Table
group by Hold
```

Then apply the update after joining it to your table:

```
update t
set Eid = S.Eid
from Test_Table t
inner join (
  select Hold, max(EID) as Eid
  from Test_Table
  group by Hold
) s on s.Hold = t.Hold
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lmHRNAYV)

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   EID    INTEGER  
  ,Hold   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Source VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(EID,Hold,Source) VALUES 
(3232,'KLME','jame.k@gmail.com'),
(NULL,'KLME','https://google.com'),
(NULL,'EEME','david.e@gmail.com'),
(NULL,'JJIN','Test@gmail.com'),
(7232,'JJIN','https://google.com');
```

use following query

```
update m1
set m1.EID=iif(m1.EID is null,m2.EID,m1.EID)
from mytable m1
join mytable m2
on m1.Hold=m2.Hold and m1.Source<>m2.Source
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5NsdfJKE)

or more simply

```
update m1
set m1.EID=m2.EID
from mytable m1
join mytable m2
on m1.Hold=m2.Hold and m1.Source<>m2.Source and m1.EID is null
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iqYt8btJ)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to get the desired outputs.
Hope this helps.

```
Create table t
(
EID varchar(20),
HOLD varchar(20),
[Source] varchar(40)
)

insert into t
Select '3232','KLME','jame.k@gmail.com'
union all select '    ','KLME','https://google.com'
union all select '    ','EEME','david.e@gmail.com'
union all select '    ','JJIN','Test@gmail.com'
union all select '7232','JJIN','https://google.com'

update t
set t.EID = t1.EID
FROM t,
(Select EID,HOLD from t where t.EID <> '') t1
where t1.HOLD = t.hold
and t.EID = ''

Select * from t

OUTPUT:

EID     HOLD    Source
---------------------------
3232    KLME    jame.k@gmail.com
3232    KLME    https://google.com
        EEME    david.e@gmail.com
7232    JJIN    Test@gmail.com
7232    JJIN    https://google.com
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**